# How does Python internally cast an int to a str?

Tags: python, string, casting, cpython

I am curious about how Python implements typecasting from an integer to a string and its performance. I was trying to find the C function for str() in the [source code's stringlib library](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Objects/stringlib) but couldn't. For a concrete example, what happens when this is evaluated:

```
>> x = 123
>> y = str(x)
>> y
'123'
```

From what I've read in the stringlib source, I believe `y` is now a `STRINGLIB_CHAR*` object, which is CPython's extended char class (please correct me if wrong). However, what algorithm is used to convert from an integer `123` to a string `"123"`? Is the time complexity linear by size (in terms of digits n) or some other characteristic of the integer? Is it just repeatedly calling modulo on the integer, filling in the string buffer from the end to the front?

Comment: This should also be in the source code.

Comment: Look at the source for int instead (longobj.c)

Comment: Specifically, the `tp_str` slot of `PyLong_Type` ... which points to `long_to_decimal_string`, which calls this internal function: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L1578

Comment: Thanks for the links. So then what I'm gathering is that the `PyObject` (referring to `x`) is converted to a `PyLongObject`, digits are calculated based on that logarithm algorithm, the array of digits is converted to the correct base, then the output string is allocated and filled, all the while keeping in mind decimal point, negative sign, etc.? So then this would be a linear time operation across the number of digits of the `PyLongObject` representation of `x`?